# Powershell start-process firefox with website and wait until firefox or tab gets closed for next command

Tags: powershell, firefox

Im trying to start firefox with a website expecting input
after finalizing the input and closing firefox or the firefox tab
the next command should start.

I've tried several approaches, but the second command is allways excecuted befor the first ended

> $proc = Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -ArgumentList "https://www.memotoo.com/de/my-addressbook-and-contacts.php?connected=1" -PassThru
>
> Wait-Process -id $proc.id
>
> powershell.exe "C:\temp\Memotoo-EMBROSERVER.ps1"

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the `-Wait` switch like this:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -ArgumentList "https://www.memotoo.com/de/my-addressbook-and-contacts.php?connected=1" -Wait

powershell.exe -file "C:\temp\Memotoo-EMBROSERVER.ps1"
```

Comment: Tried it, but it still does not wait until the firefox window or tab gets closed. It just continous with the second command

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `Sleep` statement between the two.